# How do you configure Firefox to allow Javascript to intercept a value pasted from the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, firefox, windows-vista, configuration-files, onpaste

I need to filter out certain characters when a user pastes from the clipboard. (I don't actually want to modify what's in the clipboard.) I already have this working in IE. *Sigh*...

**tl;dr:** `capability.policy` items in **user.js** make it into **prefs.js** but aren't taking effect.

FYI, I can reasonably have all users install **user.js**. But none of us have admin access to our machines, so that's about all I can do regarding configuration.

Thanks for any help!

**Note:**

1. For the purposes of this question, I do not want to "get around" accessing the clipboard -- 
   E.g., I do not want to operate on the value of the DOM element *after* a paste occurs

   I do not want a solution that requires a [framework/library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) (like jQuery, Dojo, Prototype, YUI, ...)

**Steps followed**

1. Determined location of my **profile** folder by going to URL **about:support** => Profile Directory => <kbd>Open Containing Folder</kbd>

   *Tried* to [enable clipboard in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Midas/Security_preferences) by creating **user.js** with the following lines:

   ```
   user_pref("just.mike", "test to see if user.js works.");
   user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "allowclipboard");
   user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.sites", "https://my-site.com");
   user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.Clipboard.cutcopy", "allAccess");
   user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.Clipboard.paste", "allAccess");
   ```

   *Note: https://my-site.com isn't the real site.*

   As it turns out, the `capability.policy` items are *not* visible using **about:config** -- due to [Bugzilla Bug 284673 - about:config hides "capability.policy" preferences](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=284673). However, I do think these **user.js** items "worked" and that the file is in the correct folder, because afterwards:

   - **about:config** showed the `just.mike` entry

     **prefs.js** contained all the new lines *but in a different order* -- alphabetized:

     ```
     user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.Clipboard.cutcopy", "allAccess");
     user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.Clipboard.paste", "allAccess");
     user_pref("capability.policy.allowclipboard.sites", "https://my-site.com");
     user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "allowclipboard");
     ...
     user_pref("just.mike", "test to see if user.js works.");
     ```

   (FYI, I also tried `Zallowclipboard` everywhere so that the `policynames` line came first due to alphabetization, but that didn't work either.)

   *Attempted* to [**read** the clipboard in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard#Pasting_Clipboard_Contents) after an `onpaste` event with the following:

   ```
   var clipboard = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
   if (!clipboard) {
       throw new Error('internal error -- could not create clipboard object');
   }

   var transferable = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
   if (!transferable) {
       throw new Error('internal error -- could not create transferable object');
   }

   transferable.addDataFlavor("text/unicode");
   clipboard.getData(transferable, clipboard.kGlobalClipboard);

   var clipboard_data = new Object();
   var clipboard_length = new Object();

   transferable.getTransferData("text/unicode", clipboard_data, clipboard_length);

   var clipboard_text = '';
   if (!!clipboard_data) {
       var clipboard_nsISupportsString = clipboard_data.value.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
       clipboard_text = clipboard_nsISupportsString.data.substring(0, clipboard_length.value / 2);
   }

   return(clipboard_text);
   ```

   The code fails on the *first* line, returning this error in the Firebug console:

   ```
   Permission denied for <https://my-site.com> to get property XPCComponents.classes
   ```

   *Note: I am actually running it on the real URL, which does get shown in the error message -- I've just changed it to a dummy name here.*

   I also saw [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713182/copy-to-clipboard-for-all-browsers-using-javascript) other examples where `createInstance` was used on the first line instead of `getService`, but the *first* line still generates the same error text:

   ```
   var clipboard = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
   // ...
   ```

**Environment** *(This is out of my control)*

- No admin access to computer

  Windows Vista

  Mozilla Firefox 10

**References**

- [Enable clipboard in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Midas/Security_preferences)

  [Bugzilla Bug 284673 - about:config hides "capability.policy" preferences](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=284673)

  [Access the clipboard in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard#Pasting_Clipboard_Contents)

  [Access the clipboard in Firefox in a *slightly* different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713182/copy-to-clipboard-for-all-browsers-using-javascript)

  [google: "Permission denied for" "to get property XPCComponents.classes"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Permission+denied+for%22+%22to+get+property+XPCComponents.classes%22)

Comment: You say that you don't want to "get around" accessing the clipboard. Why? It seems to me that the only solution would be to detect control-v on a textarea/input and then edit the text from there. What's wrong with that? Performance? Unless you really go wild with the text, I doubt you'll see any flicker or anything.

Comment: I have googled the issue a bit and found some code which shows the initialization of `nsIClipboard` after `nsISupportsString` and `nsITransferable`, perhaps that might influence. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard

Comment: What exactly are your problem? This may sound strange, but maybe you are overcoming your problem with what you think that can be a solution. Exposing `what you want as the final result` can give us more room to open new solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In short, I don't think it's possible to do what you want to do how you want to do it. Mozilla (and most modern browsers) limit clipboard access for security reasons. That you seem to have easily gotten around this restriction in IE is *not* a comforting thought.

That being said, plugins have different restrictions than web pages, and you may be able to get around this limitation by writing one (or maybe even leveraging flash). Even with a plugin, though, I suspect that the only way for you to block someone from pasting something into a web form (or whatever) would be to preemptively scrub their clipboard.

If all you want to do is prevent certain strings from being entered into a text box, you're best bet is to monitor events on the text box itself.

If I'm reading you right, though, it sounds like you want to force your users to type (and only type) something into a form, and I can't think of a trivial way of doing this. A couple non-trivial options:

1. Set the textbox to `readonly`, and pop-up a virtual keyboard to force the user to "type" into 
   the box using their mouse. (You'd have to build the keyboard yourself out of HTML and 
   JavaScript, or find a suitable solution somewhere.)
2. Monitor the `oninput` event; if the textbox changes more quickly then what a person could
   reasonably be expected to type, reject the changes.

Neither of those are exactly pretty, but if you want to create solutions using open web technologies, then you have to accept the *limitations* of the system you're building on top of, as well as its *benefits*.

Answer (score 0):

Grubby but crossbrowser way is to compare value of current input with previous on onchange event.

If it's length increased or value differs too much (not only reduсed but have a lot of new chars) -- probably something is pasted from clipboard.
Something like this:

```
$('input, textarea').change(function(){
  var prev = $(this).data('prev-val'), 
      current = $(this).val();
  if (is_big_changes(prev,current)) {
    $(this).val(my_filter_func(current));
  }
  if (!prev) {
     $(this).data('prev-val', current);
  } 
})
```

(it's only proof of concept, so I used jQuery to avoid a lot of coding)

Where is_big_changes and my_filter_func -- functions you need to implement.

*Warning* A lot of evil bugs is potentially possible with this approach and I know, it looks extremely ugly. My deal is to propound.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt Nayjest, but please see my "Edit to note" clarification at the top of the question.

Comment: Nayjest got the right approach, if you don't like jQuery (i have no especial love for it neither) just code the same thing with plain javascript

Answer (score 0):

Can we say, what you alternative want is detecting a clipboard paste? Since when you know what was before in there, you know what has been changed.

So why not simply hook onchange? All character identical from beginning and end of the content are not pasted. If you want to differ this from simple keystrokes, listen to keydown/keypress as well, then you know, which changes come from "elsewhere".