# cannot get document.execCommand to work properly with copying text

Tags: javascript, browser, copy-paste

Here is my code:

```
function createTextArea() {
    var t = document.createElement("textArea");
    textArea = document.body.appendChild(t);

    return textArea;
}

function copy(str) {
    var textArea = createTextArea();
    textArea.value = str;
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}

copy("hello")
```

Now, when I try to paste, the text I placed into the textarea is not appearing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo according to documentatin. From [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands) about executing commands

`copy`
Copies the current selection to the clipboard. Clipboard capability `must be enabled` in the `user.js` preference file.

And see those two posts:
[How do you configure Firefox to allow Javascript to intercept a value pasted from the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640036/how-do-you-configure-firefox-to-allow-javascript-to-intercept-a-value-pasted-fro) and 
[Copy to Clipboard for all Browsers using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713182/copy-to-clipboard-for-all-browsers-using-javascript?lq=1)

So, it seems very questionable if you can do that.