# Copy something to clipboard using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy text to the client’s clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery)

Is there any possibility to add something to clipboard (it will be string) from javascript code ? Solution has to be FF>3 IE>7 and chrome compatible

thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to use the small flash plugin, there is no way to copy to the clipboard directly with JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713182/copy-to-clipboard-for-all-browsers-using-javascript ?

Comment: I dont want to copy selected text. I have string in my javascript function and I simply want  to add it to the clipBoard

Comment: So create a container, put it there, select it and copy

Comment: @ mplungjan: which one? I dont understand

Comment: Click the link I gave to the duplicate question to find a bunch of solutions

Comment: For example zclip: `$('<a>').zclip({
        path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:"your text here"
    }).trigger();`

Comment: @gruber, give some piece of code you're working with