# Many buttons but one result in textbox in html

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

How to create a html with Many buttons but result should be displayed in one Textbox
and the text should be pre-defined i.e if Button1 is pressed it should have a predefined text should be displayed in the textbox...

And moroever if you can copy that same text in clipboard via a script....

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will get a better quality response if you show what you have already done and tried, and what you wish to accomplish based on that. Code samples are always encouraged!

Comment: Sorry about that new here(guess you'd have figure that out)but i'll be sure about it next time:)

Comment: No worries, welcome to SO!

Comment: i'd done some search but nothing seems to be promising so had try here, but i am glad i did it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following,
http://jsfiddle.net/eHzwF/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function clickedIt(buttonValue){
            document.getElementById('txt').value = buttonValue;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' id='txt' value=''/>
        <input type='button' value='Button1' onclick='clickedIt("Button1")'/>
        <input type='button' value='Button2' onclick='clickedIt("Button2")'/>
        <input type='button' value='Button3' onclick='clickedIt("Button3")'/>        
    </body>
</html>​
```

is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: That is exactly what i've been looking for thanks a ton

Comment: <!Doctype HTML> MY ORIGINAL CODE
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Fill Text Area </title>
                <script langauge="Javascript">
                        function filltxt(){
                                document.getElementById("1").value="Any text";
                        }
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <input type="button" name="btn1" value="Fill" onClick="filltxt()"/>
                <textarea id="1" rows="7" cols="25">Insert Here...</textarea>
        </body>
</html>

Comment: However can we have it copied to clipboard at the same time by any chance

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713182/copy-to-clipboard-for-all-browsers-using-javascript

Comment: and this, http://www.itjungles.com/javascript/javascript-easy-cross-browser-copy-to-clipboard-solution

Comment: It works perfectly for me "i can't thank you enogh"

Comment: Can you check this fiddle for me please http://jsfiddle.net/UDCB8/    Your querry works perfectly all i want to do with is "I WANT TO CLICK ONE BUTTON AND A PREDEFINED TEXT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED AND ALSO COPIED TO THE CLIPBOARD" FOR.EG IF WE PRESS BUTTON1 PREDEFINED TEXT LIKE "LOREM IPSUM" SHOULD BE DISPLAYED IN TEXTBOX AND COPIED TO THE CLIPBOARD ANY IDEA HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS ?I AM OK IF IT ONLY WORKS IN IE7(preference) OR ANY IE....

Comment: If it's ok that it works in IE only then this is way less code than that ^ http://jsfiddle.net/siyakunde/UDCB8/2/                          This only works with IE 4 and above

Comment: You my friend have exceeded my expections, this works flawlessly.I owe you one.

Comment: this is the last one i should ask you ,,,your script is great it just that it copies the button value instead can we do it to copy the textarea value(predefined text) that we are displaying in it.It just copies the buttonValue like Button1 but instead can we do it to text area.

Comment: done! check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/siyakunde/UDCB8/3/

Comment: Now that's what i have say <PERFECT></Thank You>