# Clipboard manipulation via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way through HTML/JavaScript to copy a line of text for the user?  So user selects a button and then text is copied, all he has to do now is go and paste it somewhere.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713182/copy-to-clipboard-for-all-browsers-using-javascript) post:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this library to manipulate the clipboard

https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard

Answer (score -2):

Can't do it with HTML or JavaScript. You'd have to use a flash or java component to copy the data to the clipboard. The reasons this is disabled is for security purposes.

An example of a flash powered method is [this one](http://www.lettersmarket.com/view_blog/a-3-copy_to_clipboard_lmcbutton.html).

Comment: It *can* be done with JavaScript, it's just not the most reliable way to do so.

Comment: It's disabled in most browsers. I'd consider that as not being able to do it.

Comment: its still not a correct answer, I found a way to do it in the Internet Explorer, however it does not carry over to other browsers.  Apparently other browser use different code to achieve this.